# Unable to load curl library on WampServer

Tags: php, apache, curl, wampserver

I really cant seem to find a solution to the cURL library not being loaded on PHP via WampServer. Am in windows 8.1 (64 bit operating system) with WampServer Apache 2.4.17, PHP 5.6.16 and mySql 5.7.9. I have tried many fixes, such as: un-commenting the ini files both in the apache and php folders. I see that php_curl is ticked when i click on the wampserver icon. However, my WampServer can't even start on its own. The light never turns green. I have to start it via the task manager, and it starts cause I get the homepage and am able to run some simple scripts on server. So, I know that it is working. Also, on the ini file there are two extension_dir: extension_dir = "C:/php/ext"
extension_dir ="C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.16/ext/"

I've checked that the php_curl.dll file is placed on C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.16/ext/. I've even moved it to C:/Windows and the apache folder but no success after restarting WampServer and checking the error logs.

I just might have to re-install WampServer one more time and take it from there.

Any advice would be helpful.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

After placing the file in he `extensions` folder, you have to enable it in the `php.ini` file for the effect to take place

Change your php.ini :

```
extension_dir = "./extensions/"
```

And uncomment `php_curl.dll` in your `php.ini` files

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Comment: okay this is the path of teh php_curl.dll it is C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.16/ext/php_cur.dll how do i enable this? in my ini file the extension_dir are like this: extension_dir = "C:/php/ext" extension_dir ="C:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.16/ext/"  how should i enable it? I dont know what you mean by extension_dir = "./extensions/" What is the string "./extensions/" referring to? @Abhinav